# toggle button for android

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, togglebutton

I am trying to create a toggle button for an android application. The toggle button would swap an image when pressed and then swapped back to the original when pressed again. I am using eclipse integrated with phonegap as my IDE. Can anyone help me with this? I've found some java source codes for android on the net but they don't seem to be workable.

Answer (score 1):

```
//get ToggleButton reference
 ToggleButton tg;
 tg = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
//set listener       
 tg.setOnClickListener(this);
//track the status of toggle button
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if((tg.isChecked()))
    {
        System.out.println("checked");
       //do wt ever you wanted to do on checked 
    }
    else
    {
            System.out.println("Unchecked");

    }
   }
```